# Do homological holes with unit coefficients correspond to polyhedra?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, homology

*(Originally [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2306291/do-homological-holes-correspond-to-polyhedra) at m.se without answers.)*

Let $T$ be a set of triangles in an abstract simplicial complex, with orientation of the triangles chosen such that

$$\partial \left( \sum \limits_{t \in T} t \right) = 0$$

where the boundary operator is as usual, and we consider coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$.
Let $S$ be the support of $T$, i.e. the set of nodes in the complex that appear in some $t \in T$.

> Does there necessarily exist a $3$-dimensional geometric realization of $T$, in the following sense:
>
> Is there a polyhedron $P$ with vertices $N$ and all triangular faces $F$, as well as a map $\phi : N \to S$ such that $\phi(F) = T$?
>
> *(where $\phi(F) = \bigcup \limits_{(a, b, c) \in F} (\phi(a), \phi(b), \phi(c))$)*

I mean "polyhedron" here in the classical sense: a 3d solid with finitely many faces, all of which are "flat," such that only adjacent faces intersect and they do so only at a boundary point or a line.  The polyhedron can be non-convex (although I suspect that this question is equivalent if we restrict to the convex case).

Comment: What do you mean by a polyhedron? A geometric realization of the complex $T$ such that two triangles intersect only along a side or a vertex and only if they do intersect in the abstract simplicial complex? Also, what do you mean by "possibly with repeats"?

Comment: @IvanIzmestiev Thanks -- I edited the post with clarifications/more precise language that will hopefully clear up these points.

Comment: Any $2D$ homology class can be realized by a map of a compact surface into the space. (This is not true in all dimensions.) Then, if you want a 3D polyhedron, just think of your surface as the boundary of a cube with several holes drilled through the middle.

Comment: A special case of your question is: given an abstract triangulation of a surface, can it be realized as a polyhedral surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$? The answer is "no", although counterexamples are complicated (in genus 6 if I remember correctly).

Comment: But I am still confused by the condition $\phi(F) = T$. Is $\phi$ a bijection between $N$ and $S$?

Comment: @IvanIzmestiev: ah I missed that. I was thinking singular homology.

Comment: @IvanIzmestiev $\phi$ doesn't need to be a bijection; you may label two nodes of the polyhedron with the same $s \in S$.  If we require $\phi$ to be a bijection then the answer to my question is "no:" generate $T$ by taking an octahedron and "gluing together" one pair of antipodal points, and then let $T$ be its faces.  We then have $\partial(T) = 0$ but no bijection to any (non-glued) polyhedron.

Comment: The conditions do imply that $\phi$ is onto $S$, though.  So $|N| \ge |S|$.

Comment: So then you mean $\phi \colon S \to N$ is surjective? And how do you realize your octahedron in the space? If you glue triangles in pairs, then your condition "only adjacent faces intersect and they do so only at a boundary point or a line" is violated.

Comment: Yes, $\phi$ will need to be surjective to have any hope of satisfying the condition.  My point with the octahedron is exactly that it *can't* be realized in space: I'm using it just to help define an abstract set of triangles $T$, and (as you've observed) this abstract set of triangles does not have a realization in space if $\phi$ is required to be a bijection.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then counterexamples are discussed on the top of page 4 of [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0412093.pdf).